# django-mongo db docker migration setup

Tags: django, mongodb, docker

```
version: "3"

services:
  rango_api:
    container_name: rango
    build: ./
    # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    working_dir: /usr/src/rango_api
    environment:
      REDIS_URI: redis://redis:6379
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://rango:27017
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/rango_api
    links:
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
      - mongo


  #redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

here is my docker-compose file for django with mongodb.
I am not able to understand where to write 'python manage.py migrate'. when i am writing before 'runserver' command it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't want to run migration every time you start a server, to valorize the concept of ephemeral container, a better solution looks like

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: your_project
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - migration
      - db
  migration:
    image: your_project
    command: python manage.py migrate --noinput
    depends_on:
      - db
```

#### Original answer

Assuming you have already done `python manage.py makemigrations`,

use `"bash -c 'python manage.py migrate --no-input && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'"`

Comment: manage.py migrate: error: unrecognized arguments: manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: @soubhagya try `"bash -c 'python manage.py migrate --no-input && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'"` , see updated answer